Mullvad VPN running on VPS causes issues with Remote Desktop connections
I want Mullvad VPN to run on my Windows VPS.
However, the moment I enable Mullvad I can no longer connect to my VPS via Remote Desktop, it simply does not connect.
Some further requirements:

I don't want to whitelist only specific IP addresses to be allowed to
connect via RDP as the IP address from which I connect changes all
the time, so I rather want to just allow all IP addresses via RDP
(who have the right credentials of course)
I don't want to overcomplicate things by using Dynamic DNS or other additional tools

Here's what I tried:

Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.
Create a new inbound rule to allow Remote Desktop connections:
Click on "Inbound Rules" in the left pane.
Click on "New Rule..." in the right pane.
Select "Port" and click "Next".
Select "TCP" and "Specific local ports: 3389", then click "Next".
Select "Allow the connection", then click "Next".
Ensure the rule applies to all profiles (Domain, Private, Public), then click "Next".
Name the rule (e.g., "Allow RDP") and click "Finish".

This did not help. What else can I try?

The client that is trying to connect to the VPS which is connected to the VPN is also connected to the same VPN?
